# Unity 3.5 doesn't run on Mac OS X 10.7.4

Tags: macos, installation

I could install this version of `Unity` on `Mac OS X 10.7.2` and it runs properly but when I do this on `10.7.4` installation completes normally but it doesn't run and the bug report screen comes up!

If you have installed Unity before upgrading to 10.7.4, it runs OK and everything's fine, but if your try to install unity after upgrading to 10.7.4, then you are going to have this problem!!!

Any ideas? other than reinstalling the whole OS from scratch...

Comment: Going through Google, it seems to be a known issue with Unity and Lion.

Comment: @RandolphWest I think you mean there is no suitable solution for this problem but reinstalling the whole OS from scratch!

Comment: Interpret it as you will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through Google, it seems to be a known issue with Unity and Lion, so it looks like you're rolling back to 10.7.2.

Comment: I wish it was better news!